# Add conditional and in array of object, mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a document like this

```
{
"_id": {
    "$oid": "5c7369826023661073802f63"
},
"participants": [
    {
        "id": "ABC",
        "nickname": "USER1",
    },
    {

        "id": "DEF",
        "nickname": "USER2",
    }
]},... etc, et
```

I want to find the record that has the two ids that you provide

I try with this.

```
moodel.aggregate([
    {
        $match:{'participants.id':idOne}
    },{
        $project:{
            list:{
                $filter:{
                    input:'$list',
                    as:'item',
                    cond: {$eq: ['$$item.participants.id', idTwo]}
                }
            },
        }
    }
])
```

but the result is:

```
[ { _id: 5c7369826023661073802f63, list: null }]
```

I want it to return only the record that match the two ids.

Answer (score 0):

> use $elematch and $in

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/

```
db.moodel.find({"participants": {$elemMatch: {id: {$in: [idOne, idTwo]}}}})
```